# Extensions of short exact sequences and second cohomology group

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology, exact-sequence

Let $G=\mathbb{I}_{p}=<g>$ be the cyclic group of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime and $A=\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ a $G-$ module with the action $g^{n}(x,y)=(x+ny,y)$. I want to show that for $p=2$ all the short exact sequences of the form $$1\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow1$$ split and for $p\neq2$ to construct a non-split sequence of the form $$1\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow1$$ I have calculated  $H^{2}(G,M)=0$ for $p=2$ and $H^{2}(G,M)=\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for $p\neq2$, so I know that the above statement is true, but I can't show it. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you showed it when you computed $H^2(G, A)$! (I think notations got a bit mixed up and $M = A$, right?) It might help to look at the proof of the relation between $H^2$ and extensions, so let's do it.

Take a short exact sequence $1 \to A \xrightarrow{i} E \xrightarrow{p} G \to 1$. Since $p$ is surjective it has a *set-theoretical* section (which is not necessarily a group morphism!) $s : G \to E$ such that $p \circ s = \operatorname{id}_G$. Then for all $g \in G$, $p^{-1}(g) = A \cdot s(g)$, so:
$$E = p^{-1}(G) = \bigsqcup_{g \in G} p^{-1}(g) = \bigsqcup_{g \in G} A \cdot s(g) \cong A \times G.$$
(The $\cong$ is just a bijection, not a group isomorphism.)

Since $p(s(g) s(h)) = p(s(g)) p(s(h)) = gh$, it follows that $s(g)s(h) \in p^{-1}(gh)$, so there is an element $\alpha_s(g,h) \in A$ such that
$$s(g) s(h) = \alpha_s(g,h) s(gh).$$
Now the product $s(g)s(g')s(g'')$ is associative, and if you write down what it means, you will see that it is equivalent to $\alpha_s : G \times G \to E$ being a $2$-cocycle! (And here you really need to use that the short exact sequence is a sequence of $G$-modules, something that you didn't mention.)

Conversely, given such a $2$-cocycle $\beta$, you can define a product on the set $A \times G$:
$$(a,g) \cdot (a', g') := (a g a' \beta(g,g'), gg').$$
You then get a $G$-module $E_\beta$ and a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to E_\beta \to G \to 1$. If you apply the previous construction with the section $s : g \mapsto (1,g) \in A \times G$, you get back a $2$-cocycle $\alpha_s$ which is cohomologous to $\beta$ (verify it).

Now if $\beta$ is a coboundary, the section of the projection $A \times G \to G$, $g \mapsto (1, g)$ becomes a group homomorphism. In fact, it's equivalent to $\beta$ being a coboundary. So if you know that $H^2(G,A) = 0$, then every cocycle is a coboundary and there always exists a splitting of the short exact sequence.

Conversely, suppose $\beta$ is *not* a coboundary (ie. $[\beta] \in H^2(G, A)$ is nonzero). Then if the short exact sequence. were split with section $s$, you could apply the construction to get a cocycle $\alpha_s$, cohomologous to $\beta$. The fact that you applied the construction to a split short exact sequence. means that $\alpha_s$ is a coboundary, and since $\alpha_s \sim \beta$, $\beta$ is a coboundary too. Contradiction: the short exact sequence cannot be split. So if you choose $[\beta] \neq 0 \in H^2(G,A)$, you can construct the non-split short exact sequence $1 \to A \to E_\beta \to G \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your proof was very good. Does not exist an explicit example of a non- split short exact for p$\neq$2?

Comment: You can use your proof that $H^2(G, A) \neq 0$ to find an explicit cocycle $\beta$ which isn't a coboundary. Then $1 \to A \to E_\beta \to G \to 1$ is an explicit non-split short exact sequence. $E_\beta = A \times G$ as a set, and the group law is explicit (depending on $\beta$). FYI, if you found my answer useful, you can vote on it by clicking on the arrows, and you can also accept it by clicking the check mark if it solved your problem. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: To be honest i don't understand very well what you say

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I understand your point but I want to construct explicitly a non-split short exact, i.e to find the maps i,p and to prove that E is not a semidirect product of the other two

Comment: Well here $E = A \times G$ as a set. The multiplication is given by $(a,g) \cdot (a', g') = (aga' \beta(g,g'), gg')$. $i(a) = (a, 1)$ and $p(a,g) = g$. To prove that it cannot be split, you have to actually do the computations. Suppose you have a splitting, then (1) it gives you a cocycle $\alpha$ like in my answer. Since the splitting is a group morphism you find that (2) $\alpha$ is a coboundary. Since (3) $\alpha \sim \beta$, $\beta$ is a coboundary too (4). That's a contradiction. I made four claims (1) (2) (3) (4) here that you need to check by writing down the definitions.